# pour vs dump waste

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I came across the following dialogue in a text-book written by a non-native speaker.
In the dialogue it says "
In my hometown, water pollution is an important 
problem. There are a lot of factories and they pour their 
waste into the river."

Can we use pour here? I have looked it up and I couldn't find anything proper in my dictionaries. For instance, Longman gives this example
The company was fined for dumping toxic waste in the sea.
So can we use pour here or not?[image: pour in the text-book]

Comment: How do you know the writer is a non-native?

Comment: The names of the writers are on the cover the book.

Comment: Native speakers can have non-English names. The text is relatively simple, so it could well be written by a very competent speaker or by someone who is bi-lingual. I don't see anything that stands out as being awkward or clumsy sounding.

Comment: “A car owner who does not know better can get the immediate idea to [pour waste oil](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=MI1lW779OMeo0gLYv4XgDA&q=%22pour+waste+oil%22&oq=%22pour+waste+oil%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...22871.23607.0.24231.4.4.0.0.0.0.137.486.0j4.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.375...0i30k1j0i10i30k1j0i5i30k1j0i8i30k1j0i8i10i30k1j0i8i7i30k1j33i10k1.0.hamy7L7SFio) right on the ground or in a nearby pond.”

Comment: This is a national text-book written by Turkish writers who are notorious for making clumsy mistakes. Would you trust a writer who can make  sentences like "I have eggs at breakfast?" ,"I will attend to a party" or "I study at 8th grade", "The temperature is exceeding 40 oC in the afternoon every day.", "Taj Mahal is one of the eight wonders of the world. It is in Agra, India. The Emperor Shah Jahan ordered it in memory of his third wife, Mumtaz Mahal." These are the sort of sentences of we have to deal with every year in our text books.

Comment: OK, yes those examples do sound "off". Little mistakes that show the authors are not native speakers.

Comment: Yes, you can use *pour* there. It implies straight-piping waste into the rivers. *Discharge* is the preferred term.

Comment: @PhilSweet preferred where, by whom, in what context?

Answer (score 2):

**pour** is (often)* used to describe anything in liquid form that moves in a stream, while **dump** refers to the disposal of any type of unwanted liquid and/or solid material. **pouring waste** usually refers to the disposal of liquid matter, while **dumping waste** suggests that the materials being dumped can either be liquids, solids, or (usually) the combination of both.

When it comes to general usage, [**dumping waste** is much more prevalent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=pour%20waste%2Cdump%20waste&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpour%20waste%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdump%20waste%3B%2Cc0), though **pouring waste** does have its uses, especially when it comes to describing the disposal of liquid waste.

Therefore, the textbook is technically correct in its usage of the word.

*Additional note: Pour can also be used to refer to non-liquid objects that come or go in a steady stream and in large numbers, e.g letters poured in, people poured out of the theater, etc. Despite this, the word is very rarely used in conjunction with **waste** itself.